# Deployment with wildfly

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, wildfly-9

I am working on an Ear Web application with Maven, Ejb, Jsf and hibernate on Eclipse using Wildfly 9.
I kind of followed this tutorial [ear maven web application](http://myblog-itsolutions.rhcloud.com/pages/java-ee-6/ear-maven-jboss.xhtml?postId=9). I have this project structure :

[image: project structure]

I am supposed to run the ABank-ear on server. When I run it I get 404 and this stack trace

```
17:03:04,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "ABank-web.war")
17:03:04,287 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ABank-ear.ear".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ABank-ear.ear".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "ABank-ear.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ds.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:105)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1731)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipSpaces(XMLEntityScanner.java:1482)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:838)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:558)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:1238)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:107)
    at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ds.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:90)
    ... 6 more

17:03:04,292 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ABank-ear.ear\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"ABank-ear.ear\".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"ABank-ear.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
17:03:04,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "ABank-ear.ear" with deployment "ABank-ear.ear"
17:03:04,663 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0185:    Newly corrected services:
      service jboss.module.service."deployment.ABank-ear.ear.ABank-ejb.jar".main (no longer required)
      service jboss.module.service."deployment.ABank-ear.ear.ABank-web.war".main (no longer required)
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."ABank-ear.ear".PARSE
      service jboss.deployment.unit."ABank-ear.ear".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ABank-ear.ear".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "ABank-ear.ear"
```

any help with it please .

Edition: 
Its a three modules in one maven project: ear module, ejb module and web module.
Pom file for the ejb module

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>ABank</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.pl</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>ABank-ejb</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>ABank - ejb</name>

    <url>http://jboss.org/jbossas</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All of 
            them are provided by JBoss AS 7 -->

        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test scope dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
        <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and 
            Transactional(JTA) JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>               
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Tell Maven we are using EJB 3.1 -->
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it 
                to run just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including 
                Arquillian tests that execute in the specified container -->
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests 
                in your JBoss AS instance -->
            <!-- This profile will start a new JBoss AS instance, and execute 
                the test, shutting it down when done -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-managed -->
            <id>arq-jbossas-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests 
                in a remote JBoss AS instance -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-remote -->
            <id>arq-jbossas-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

</project>
```

the pom of the web module

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
      <artifactId>ABank</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.pl</groupId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>

   <artifactId>ABank-web</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <name>ABank - web</name>

   <url>http://jboss.org/jbossas</url>
   <licenses>
      <license>
         <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
         <distribution>repo</distribution>
         <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
      </license>
   </licenses>

   <dependencies>

      <!-- Dependency on the EJB module so we can use it's services if needed -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.pl</groupId>
         <artifactId>ABank-ejb</artifactId>
         <type>ejb</type>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
         <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

       <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
       <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
       <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
               <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What is in your pom?

Comment: I have 4 pom files, I am going to post the ear module pom

Comment: Actually the WAR and JAR (ejb) ones are the most important. It's possible a dependency is being included in the archive that shouldn't be. You'll want to inspect the scope for each dependency and ensure it's set to `<scope>included</scope>` for any dependencies the server provides.

Comment: I will include them then in my question